# How to add both send and enter imeoptions in android soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

Caps lock is on I want to add new line in edittext

[image: Caps lock is on I want to add new line in edittext]

Caps lock is off I want to send imeopetions in sof keyboard

[image: caps lock is off I want to send imeopetions in sof keyboard]

**please help me**.

Comment: I shown in apps. That means there are using custom. right?

Comment: so for that what you have tried ?

Comment: @AmitVaghela I tried to add `setOnEditorActionListener` to `Editext`. But It's not working.